# Cannot get user info with user id (Unsupported get request)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to check if the user liked a specific page in Facebook, with the code below, I get the Facebook ID: 1457943711113514, however, this seems to have problem as I cannot get anything with graph api, and it gave me the message "Unsupported get request." as follow:

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1457943711113514&version=v2.0)

obtained and checked with code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
       console.log(response.authResponse);
       var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

       FB.api("/me/likes/{target_facebook_page_id}", {access_token: accessToken}, function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);

       if (response.data.length == 1) {

           //do sth if liked already

       } else if (response.data.length == 0) {

           //do sth if not yet liked
       }
 });
```

While I can get them with another ID (I guess it is v1.0's ID?), which is 1462582470649638:

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1462582470649638&version=v2.0)

And I am only able to access user's liked pages with the later one, this makes me very frustrated, hope anyone can help. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I just tried a simple version of my file, which the code is shown as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="js/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="js/encode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script src="<%= request.getScheme()%>://connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/sdk.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        var intUid;
        var userList = new Array();

        function logout() {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { console.log("Ready");


            FB.init({
                appId: '1439635652957313',
                status: true, // check login statu
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
                version: 'v2.0',
                oauth: true
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse){
                    console.log("authed (2)");
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not authed (2)");
                }
            });

        });

    </script>       
</body>
```

It still gives me the userID 1457943711113514, which I cannot get any valid usable info from it. Have been trying this whole day, really hope someone can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: {target_facebook_page_id} should actually be the id. Is it? And I don't think you should need to specify the access_token in the request. FB.api I think do that for you

Comment: Yes it is the actual id. I tried removing the access token, seems it doesn't change anything.

Comment: "Unsupported get request" hints that the id is not a User id. Are you sure about that? And, have you requested the `user_likes` permission? Respectively, are you sure the actual access token contains the said permission?

Comment: I just tried a simple version of the file, and it still gives me that userID, which I cannot get any valid info from it, updated my code above.

Comment: I think `1457943711113514` is your app scoped ID, correct me if I'm wrong, because your user id is 100006936976786

Comment: I also think it is my app scoped ID, but how can I get user liked pages with this ID? My test account liked several pages, but it is giving an empty data array with FB.api("me/likes", ...)

Comment: API 2.0. changelog says that you can't query users with their ID, instead use `me/endpoint` - checked, `FB.api("me/likes", ...)` returns empty `data` object/array, then you're missing the permission `user_likes` as @Tobi said